# SOLID principles in mvp architecture

Tags: ios, swift

I use model view presenter architecture in my app and I wonder what's better for respect solid principles and reusability.

So I have 4 classes: View Controller, Presenter, Model and Service. But I have a doubt in connection between presenter and service. I am not sure if I don't break single responsibility principle.

Presenter:

```
class WorkoutPresenter() {
  // some code

    let workoutSettingsService = WorkoutSettingsService()
    
    func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInHistory() {
        workoutSettingsService.changeUnitFromKGtoLBInHistory()
    }
    
    func changeUnitFromLBtoKGInHistory() {
        workoutSettingsService.firstFunction()
    }
    
    func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInCalendar() {
        workoutSettingsService.secondFunction()
    }
}

class WorkoutSettingService {

  func firstFunction() {
         // some code
  }
  func secondFunction() {
            // some code
  }
  func thirdFunction() {
          // some code 
  }

}
```

Now workout service has 3 responsibilities (first, second and third function)
Or maybe better option would be create different class for each function and then call them in WorkoutService, something like:

```
class WorkoutSettingService {
    
    let firstFunctionClass: FirstFunctionClass
    let secondFunctionClass: SecondFunctionClass
    let thirdFunction: ThirdFunctionClass
    
    init(firstFunctionClassClass: FirstFunction, secondFunctionClass: SecondFunctionClass, thirdFunctionClass: ThirdFunctionClass) {
        self.firstFunctionClass = firstFunction
        self.secondFunctionClass = secondFunction
        self.thirdFunctionClass = thirdFunction
      
    }
    
    func firstFunctionCall() {
        firstFunctionClass.function()
    }
    func secondFunctionCall() {
        secondFunctionClass.function()
    }
    func thirdFunctionCall() {
        thirdFunctionClass.function()
    }
}
```

And then call it in Presenter like before. Or maybe better than accessing to this new three class is create a protocols and set delegates from service to this new specific classes?

I hope you understand what my problem is. If you have other idea how to connect presenter with service in clean way, go ahead.

Comment: Class should be single purpose, not single function, or single responsibility. So by having 3 functions that have the same overall meaning (unit conversion) you are not breaking any principles. The other thing is whether you really need function per type of conversion or you could have a generic function `func convert<T>(_ value: T, from: Unit, to: Unit)` (or something like that). Or why do you even need to wrap service functions with functions from some other class?

Comment: I need to wrap it because, accordingly to model view presenter architecture, my view needs to communicate with presenter and should not have knowledge about others than presenter. In my app I have segmented control in my view, when segmented controll changes it calls function from presenter e.g. first function which is changeUnitFromKGtoLBInHistory() and this function call service, which change data in database. Thanks to that my view doesn't have knowledge about service and others class except for presenter. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: And I have one another question, if I use Settings Service instance, its not breaking Dependency Inversion Principle, this classes are not tightly coupled? Maybe better approach is creating delegate between presenter and service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner approach in my opinion would be to introduce **protocols** to your service class and segregate the responsibilities.

To make the example simpler, I am going to assume that `func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInHistory()` and `func changeUnitFromLBtoKGInHistory()` have to invoke a service with respect to some history data and the `func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInCalendar()` has to invoke current calendar data.

First we introduce 2 protocols to do that

```
protocol InHistoryServiceProtocol {
    func firstFunction()
    func secondFunction()
}

protocol InCalendatServiceProtocol {
    func thirdFunction()
}
```

Then we update the `class WorkoutSettingService` to conform to protocol as below:

```
class WorkoutSettingService: InHistoryServiceProtocol, InCalendatServiceProtocol {

  func firstFunction() {
         // some code
  }
  func secondFunction() {
            // some code
  }
  func thirdFunction() {
          // some code
  }

}
```

Now we use protocol composition to gracefully handle the service class in the presenter

```
class WorkoutPresenter {
  // some code
    typealias WorkoutServiceProtocols = InHistoryServiceProtocol & InCalendatServiceProtocol

    let workoutSettingsService: WorkoutServiceProtocols = WorkoutSettingService()
    
    func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInHistory() {
        workoutSettingsService.firstFunction()
    }
    
    func changeUnitFromLBtoKGInHistory() {
        workoutSettingsService.secondFunction()
    }
    
    func changeUnitFromKGtoLBInCalendar() {
        workoutSettingsService.thirdFunction()
    }
}
```

This way you have the flexibility to add/remove responsibilities in the Work out service class respecting the SOLID principles. It also becomes easy to mock the data and inject into presenter for testing.